# spaCy v3 train NER based on existing model or add custom trained NER to existing model

Tags: python, machine-learning, spacy, named-entity-recognition

in spaCy < 3.0 I was able to train the NER component within the trained *en_core_web_sm model*:

```
python -m spacy train en model training validation --base-model en_core_web_sm --pipeline "ner" -R -n 10
```

Specifically, I need the tagger and in the parser of the *en_core_web_sm* model.
spaCy's new version doesn't take these commands anymore, they need to be set in the config file. According to spaCy's website these components can be added with the corresponding source and then insert to the frozen_component in the training section of the config file (*I will provide my full config at the end of this question*):

```
[components]

[components.tagger]
source = "en_core_web_sm"
replace_listeners = ["model.tok2vec"]

[components.parser]
source = "en_core_web_sm"
replace_listeners = ["model.tok2vec"]
.
.
.
[training]
frozen_components = ["tagger","parser"]
```

When I'm debugging, following error occurs:

```
ValueError: [E922] Component 'tagger' has been initialized with an output dimension of 49 - cannot add any more labels.
```

When I put tagger to the disabled components in the nlp section of the config file or if I delete everything related to the tagger, debugging and training works. However, when applying the trained model to a text loaded to a doc, only the trained NER works and none of the other components. E.g. the parser predicts everything is *ROOT*.

I also tried to train the NER model on its own and then add it to the loaded en_core_web_sm model:

```
MODEL_PATH = 'data/model/model-best'
nlp = spacy.load(MODEL_PATH)

english_nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

ner_labels = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
english_nlp.add_pipe('ner_labels')
```

This leads to the following error:

```
ValueError: [E002] Can't find factory for 'ner_labels' for language English (en). This usually happens when spaCy calls `nlp.create_pipe` with a custom component name that's not registered on the current language class. If you're using a Transformer, make sure to install 'spacy-transformers'. If you're using a custom component, make sure you've added the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory` (for class components).

Available factories: attribute_ruler, tok2vec, merge_noun_chunks, merge_entities, merge_subtokens, token_splitter, parser, beam_parser, entity_linker, ner, beam_ner, entity_ruler, lemmatizer, tagger, morphologizer, senter, sentencizer, textcat, textcat_multilabel, en.lemmatizer
```

**Does anyone have a suggestion how I can either train my NER with the *en_core_web_sm* model or how I could integrate my trained component?**

Here's the full config file:

```
[paths]
train = "training"
dev = "validation"
vectors = null
init_tok2vec = null

[system]
gpu_allocator = null
seed = 0

[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","tagger","parser","ner"]
batch_size = 1000
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}

[components]

[components.tagger]
source = "en_core_web_sm"
replace_listeners = ["model.tok2vec"]

[components.parser]
source = "en_core_web_sm"
replace_listeners = ["model.tok2vec"]

[components.ner]
factory = "ner"
moves = null
update_with_oracle_cut_size = 100

[components.ner.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "ner"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 64
maxout_pieces = 2
use_upper = true
nO = null

[components.ner.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.tok2vec]
factory = "tok2vec"

[components.tok2vec.model]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2Vec.v2"

[components.tok2vec.model.embed]
@architectures = "spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
attrs = ["NORM","PREFIX","SUFFIX","SHAPE"]
rows = [5000,2500,2500,2500]
include_static_vectors = false

[components.tok2vec.model.encode]
@architectures = "spacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v2"
width = 256
depth = 8
window_size = 1
maxout_pieces = 3

[corpora]

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 2000
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[training]
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
train_corpus = "corpora.train"
seed = ${system.seed}
gpu_allocator = ${system.gpu_allocator}
dropout = 0.1
accumulate_gradient = 1
patience = 1600
max_epochs = 0
max_steps = 20000
eval_frequency = 200
frozen_components = ["tagger","parser"]
before_to_disk = null

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_words.v1"
discard_oversize = false
tolerance = 0.2
get_length = null

[training.batcher.size]
@schedules = "compounding.v1"
start = 100
stop = 1000
compound = 1.001
t = 0.0

[training.logger]
@loggers = "spacy.ConsoleLogger.v1"
progress_bar = false

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
L2_is_weight_decay = true
L2 = 0.01
grad_clip = 1.0
use_averages = false
eps = 0.00000001
learn_rate = 0.001

[training.score_weights]
ents_per_type = null
ents_f = 1.0
ents_p = 0.0
ents_r = 0.0

[pretraining]

[initialize]
vectors = "en_core_web_lg"
init_tok2vec = ${paths.init_tok2vec}
vocab_data = null
lookups = null
before_init = null
after_init = null

[initialize.components]

[initialize.tokenizer]
```

Comment: I'm running up against the same problem. I'm trying to add a pipe from a custom trained pipeline and am receiving the "Can't find factory" error when I try to load the model with the custom pipeline. If you've found a solution I would love to hear it.

Comment: I still haven't solved my issues. Instead I've downgraded to spaCy 2.3.5. However, this  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGM7lXfQECM) might help you with the factory error (but the video is for spaCy < 3.0).

Comment: Spacy added a discussion board on their GitHub page where one of the dev's answered my problem (try reposting your question there). But I'm going to scope out that video as well as I still have a lot to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I provided a longer answer on spaCy's discussion forum [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7149), but in a nutshell if you want to source and freeze your parser/tagger, use this in the config:

```
[components.tagger]
source = "en_core_web_sm"
replace_listeners = ["model.tok2vec"]

[components.parser]
source = "en_core_web_sm"
replace_listeners = ["model.tok2vec"]

[components.tok2vec]
source = "en_core_web_sm"
```

i.e. make sure that the tagger & parser can connect to the correct `tok2vec` instance they were initially trained on.

You can then create an independent NER component either on top of the sourced (and pretrained) `tok2vec`, or create a new internal `tok2vec` component for the NER, or create a second `tok2vec` component with a distinct name, that you refer to as the `upstream` argument of the NER's `Tok2VecListener`.

Comment: Generally speaking if I'm just adding more attributes (ie/ IS_PUNC) to my tok2vec... which of those 3 options are recommended?